# What means count of four from this two variants?

Tags: count

What does "count of four" mean of these two possibilities?

a) 1, 2, 3, 4

or

b) 4

Sorry for silly question, but I'm interested and have a bad understanding of this.

Comment: [correction: What ***does*** X mean.]//I am interested **in it** not I'm interesting.]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**It can mean either depending on context.**

For example if a musician says:

> Give me a count of four.

they expect the band leader to count "One two three four" to start the music.

If someone says:

> I have a count of four people in the room.

it means I have counted the people in the room and there are four of them.

Comment: And of course there’s , “We’ll jump on the count of four.”

Comment: As the OP readily admits, this **is** a silly question, so why have you chased rep points by posting an immediate answer? You've undermined us all: now that the answer has been accepted, this useless question is condemned to remain in our EL&U library, impervious to the SE algorithm that deletes old closed questions with negative scores.